# Customize Logic on Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

I am trying to amend an existing process builder that sends out emails when we reschedule a job. Right now it is set to send when a date and time is updated. We would like this to send when the date is updated, when the time is updated and when both date and time are updated.

I tried customizing the logic but I am not able to set it up correctly.

1 AND 3 AND 4
OR 2 AND 3 AND 4
OR 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4

Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) then [edit] your question to explain where you are stuck and what you've already tried. As it stands this question is likely to be closed without answer.

Comment: NB: You need to consider brackets to ensure you have the required precedence between the various parts of your logic expression.

Comment: Thank you Phil. Can I do it this way: 1 AND 3 AND 4 OR (2 AND 3 AND 4) OR 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4       I need to make the process builder work on those different scenarios.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add detail of what you are trying to do, what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Done editing my question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To handle when 1 changes or 2 changes or both change you only need an expression of "1 OR 2".

Comment: Thanks. So I can do: (1 OR 2) AND 3 AND 4 (OR 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4)? Working on customization for the first time.

Comment: Your question only explains you have two values being tested. What are 3 and 4 here?